# Controller not rendering show.js.haml during AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml, ujs

I'm making a simple AJAX call from a from_tag (search box) and want to show the results without refreshing page. The issue is that even though I can see in server console that the show action is being processed as JS, it still renders the HTML and not the js.haml file.  The only way I'm getting controller to render js is by changing name to show.js . It then works as it should. show.js.erb doesn't work either. I've also tried format.js {render layout: false} without any luck.  It seem to be an problem on the controller side but I might be wrong here. Any ideas appreciated!

**Edit:**

The controller action is working using the render "show.js.haml" option. The other issue is that escape_javascript doesn't do anything in below js.haml file.

show.js.haml

```
$("#main").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'artists/show', locals: {artist: @artist, updates, @updates, reach: @reach, reach_diff: @reach_diff})}");
```

controller

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

        def index
            if params[:search]
                @artist=Artist.find_by(name: params[:search])
                redirect_to action: "show", id: @artist.id
            else
                @artists= Artist.all
            end
        end

        def show
            @artist= Artist.find(params[:id])
            @updates = @artist.updates.order(created_at: :desc)
            @reach = @artist.reachupdates.order(created_at: :desc)
            @reach_diff= Reachupdate.last_week_diff(@artist.id)

            respond_to do |format|
                format.html
                format.js {render "show.js.haml", layout: false}
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Try `render 'show.js.haml', layout: false`

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `render layout: false` to `render 'show.js.haml', layout: false`

```
def show
  @artist= Artist.find(params[:id])
  @updates = @artist.updates.order(created_at: :desc)
  @reach = @artist.reachupdates.order(created_at: :desc)
  @reach_diff= Reachupdate.last_week_diff(@artist.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {render 'show.js.haml', layout: false}
  end
end
```

**Update:**

> The next issue I'm having is to insert ruby objects to the js file

If the file `'articles/show'` is a *partial file* then the problem is the `locals` keyword should be used along with `partial` keyword in order to work. Try changing this

```
$("#main").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'artists/show', locals: {artist: @artist, updates, @updates, reach: @reach, reach_diff: @reach_diff})}");
```

to

```
$("#main").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'artists/show', locals: {artist: @artist, updates, @updates, reach: @reach, reach_diff: @reach_diff})}");
```

Or

Just remove `locals`

```
$("#main").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'artists/show', artist: @artist, updates, @updates, reach: @reach, reach_diff: @reach_diff)}");
```

Comment: This is working and correct file is being rendered. The next issue I'm having is to insert ruby objects to the js file. Would like to use js.haml here since it's what's used for the rest of the application.

The show.js.haml is very simple and looks like this:
$("#main").html("#{escape_javascript(@artist.name)}");

Comment: @OscarSidebo I've updated my answer. Please accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't :/ . The output is using that code is just the Ruby statement. (local variables removed for brevity). <%= escape_javascript(render 'artists/show', locals: {…] %>

Comment: @OscarSidebo Are you putting it inside the quotes right? `"<%= escape_javascript(render 'artists/show', locals: {artist: @artist, updates, @updates, reach: @reach, reach_diff: @reach_diff}) %>"`

Comment: Yes. And if inspecting HTML it shows up exactly like that including the quotes. It seem that just gets processed as a string. Really frustrating! Can't help to think this has to do with HAML possibly?  I would like to use HAML but will do a lot of AJAX and not worth if this is the headache that comes with it…

Comment: @OscarSidebo Apologies. I've realized that you are using haml. Deleted my update.

Comment: @OscarSidebo Is the file `'articles/show'` is a partial file?

Comment: It's not a partial but I tried changing it into a partial with underscore in beginning of name and that didn't make a difference.  Also tried both of your syntax suggestions above. It's still just outputting that whole statement as a string. Somehow whatever is inside #{} isn't executing at all.

Comment: Okay seem to have find a clue as to why this isn't working because when I try to render index.js.erb instead of redirecting to show action first it works fine with both erb and haml.